# Run 2008 R2 Service under 2000 Domain Account

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, cruisecontrol

I'm trying to get a service to run under a domain account. When I try to add the account, I get the error

> The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account 
>   name specified

I know the account exists and the password is correct. I am also having trouble adding it manually to the "Log on as a service" setting, I get the error

> An extended error has occured. Failed to save Local Policy Database

After a day of research I'm starting to suspect it has to do with it being a 2008 R2 server trying to use a 2000 domain account. I've tried to change the LAN Manager authentication level and the Minimum session security looks okay per my Google digging. I'm not sure what else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that 2008R2 had trouble looking up SIDs when we tried to install vCenter that needed to run as a domain account on a 2000 domain. There is a microsoft hotfix available for it. Google for 2008R2 and vCenter and you'll find it.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't run into that. Guess I didn't search for the right thing. Thank You!